# KeyError: Cannot load `Rails.application.database_configuration`: key not found: "DB_ENV_POSTGRESQL_USER"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

So I have been looking everywhere to try and find a solution to this and i have had no luck up to now. I'm ruby on rails so i could very well be missing something basic or be looking in the wrong place for the solution, so i thought i'd just ask. I have a rails API which i forked from my organization and I want to run it locally. I got stuck running this line in the terminal

```
bundle exec rake create:db
```

and got this error, I don't really know what to do :/ If this question has already been answered just point me there and i'll go figure it out! Thank you.

```
 

Admins-MacBook-Pro:environments nathanshanko$ bundle exec rake db:create
(in /Users/nathanshanko/Desktop/git-repos/voke_api)
rake aborted!
KeyError: Cannot load `Rails.application.database_configuration`:
key not found: "DB_ENV_POSTGRESQL_USER"
(erb):7:in `fetch'
(erb):7:in `'
/Users/nathanshanko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:104:in `database_configuration'
/Users/nathanshanko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:41:in `block (3 levels) in '
/Users/nathanshanko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/nathanshanko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `'
KeyError: key not found: "DB_ENV_POSTGRESQL_USER"
(erb):7:in `fetch'
(erb):7:in `'
/Users/nathanshanko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:104:in `database_configuration'
/Users/nathanshanko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:41:in `block (3 levels) in '
/Users/nathanshanko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/nathanshanko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `'
Tasks: TOP => db:create => db:load_config
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Here is my database.yml file

```
 common: &common
 adapter: postgresql
 encoding: utf8
reconnect: true
pool: <%= ENV['DB_ENV_POSTGRESQL_POOL'] || 5 %>
database: <%= ENV['DB_ENV_POSTGRESQL_DB'] || 'voke_api' %>
username: <%= ENV.fetch('DB_ENV_POSTGRESQL_USER') %>
password: <%= ENV['DB_ENV_POSTGRESQL_PASS'] %>
host: <%= ENV.fetch('DB_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR') %>
port: <%= ENV['DB_PORT_5432_TCP_PORT'] %>

 development:
 <<: *common


production:
<<: *common



 staging:
  <<: *common

  test:
   <<: *common
```

Comment: Do you have `config/database.yml` file

Comment: yes I do.  this is what it look like, ill add it as an update

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're missing some env vars that define your database credentials. You'll want to set these up (either via the command line, or something like a `.env` or `application.yml` file, depending on your project set up).

The error you're getting on `DB_ENV_POSTGRESQL_USER` is due to the `ENV.fetch`, which raises an `IndexError` if the key isn't found. You may also be missing other env vars, but `ENV['xyz']` will fail silently without throwing any errors.

Comment: This is correct. `ENV.fetch` should be used with a default value or a failsafe. 
For example:
`ENV.fetch('DB_ENV_POSTGRESQL_USER', 'postgres')` 
Or add a message that it was not found:
`ENV.fetch('DB_ENV_POSTGRESQL_USER') { |key| puts "env var #{key} not found"}`